# Equivalent of R's group_by, filter, duplicate in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am in the process of moving some of my code from R to Python, however, I am having trouble on something which seemed quite easy in R. I have checked SO and other resources, but haven't found a direct solution.

Essentially, I am trying to understand the equivalents of Group_by, filter, and duplicate in Python.

In R - my solution (which is what I am trying to copy in Python) is:

```
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% filter(!duplicated(id))
```

I have tried

```
 df.groupby('Date').drop_duplicates(keep='first')
```

but I get the following error:

```
Cannot access callable attribute 'drop_duplicates' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

sample dataset and expected output:

```
id   date   rev
 1   1/1/18  20.4
 1   1/2/18  20.1
 1   1/2/18  20.01
 1   1/3/18  20.6
 2   1/1/18  16.4
 2   1/1/18  15.4
 2   1/2/18  17.5
 2   1/3/18  18.9
```

Expected Results:

```
id   date  rev
1   1/1/18  20.4
1   1/2/18  20.1
1   1/3/18  20.6
2   1/1/18  16.4
2   1/2/18  17.5
2   1/3/18  18.9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(['date','id'],keep='first')
Out[985]: 
   id    date   rev
0   1  1/1/18  20.4
1   1  1/2/18  20.1
3   1  1/3/18  20.6
4   2  1/1/18  16.4
6   2  1/2/18  17.5
7   2  1/3/18  18.9
```

Also in R with one call

```
df %>% distinct(date, id)
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it!